# How to mute a tab in google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, mute

It is difficult to selectively mute the content that is making sound in google chrome. I have to locate the tab and then scroll up and down to find the content that is producing sound. It would be great if there exist a feature which will let me right click on the tab and say "Mute".

Is there any way to achieve this without using extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type this in Google Chrome's omnibox

```
chrome://flags/#enable-tab-audio-muting
```

You will see this listing

```
Enable tab audio muting UI control. Windows, Linux, Chrome OS
When enabled, the audio indicators in the tab strip double as tab audio mute controls. This also adds commands in the tab context menu for quickly muting multiple selected tabs. #enable-tab-audio-muting.
```

Click Enable link at the bottom of this. Restart Chrome to get this feature.

**Note** : This feature is supported in Google Chrome builds upwards of version 39

**Reference**: http://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/mute-noisy-tabs-in-google-chrome-1683215637

Comment: You can do more by this chrome extension. https://github.com/ssgaur/PauseTabSound